# Get a long-running-process' output stream

Tags: shell, unix, clojure

There's a long-running Unix process which output I'd wish to capture and process with Clojure. A good example of one such process is a repl-y / nREPL session: its duration is indefinite, and output gets printed to stdout.

If I try `(clojure.java.io/sh "lein" "repl")`, evaluation will block until the underlying process finishes, and *then* I can observe the output.

This is not what I want - I want to get a stream immediately instead.

Can I achieve this using clojure.java.io, or similar, existing Clojure tools? Wouldn't mind resorting to Java otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [me.raynes.conch](https://github.com/Raynes/conch) library, it's a bit more versatile than clojure.java.shell. It's [low-level API](https://github.com/Raynes/conch#low-level-usage) seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think to stream-process stdout, more technique is needed outside of conch, if you want to handle the output stream in a non-blocking way, or at least, it's not obvious to me how to accomplish that with conch.

Answer (score 2):

Not a detailed answer, but the [source](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/4bea7a529bb14b99d48758cfaf0d71af0997f0ff/src/clj/clojure/java/shell.clj#L63) for Clojure's `sh` function is pretty short.  If you reworked it slightly to remove the `.waitFor` (or added a higher-order function to consume the partial reads returned by the `InputStreamReader` as they arrived), you could probably get updated data as it's returned by the process.  But be careful of deadlocks in case your subprocess expects input as well (as in your `lein repl` example).